# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is monotonic, bounded and its limit is 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is monotonic, bounded and its limit is 1, for $\alpha>0$

**My attempt**

I guess the solution depends on whether $\alpha$ is greater than 1 or less than 1. Right?

For  $\alpha>1$

*Monotonicity*: By induction:

If n=1 $\rightarrow \alpha>1$

If n=2 $\rightarrow \alpha>\sqrt[2]{\alpha}>1$

If n=3 $\rightarrow \alpha>\sqrt[2]{\alpha}>\sqrt[3]{\alpha}>1$

If n=N $\rightarrow \alpha>\sqrt[2]{\alpha}>\sqrt[3]{\alpha}...>\sqrt[N]{\alpha}>1$

If n=N+1 $\rightarrow \alpha>\sqrt[2]{\alpha}>\sqrt[3]{\alpha}...>\sqrt[N]{\alpha}>\sqrt[N+1]{\alpha}>1$

So, for any N, $\sqrt[N]{\alpha}>\sqrt[N+1]{\alpha}$ is always true. Then $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is monotonically decreasing.

*Boundedness*:

We have that $\sqrt[N]{\alpha}<\alpha$ is always true. So $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is bounded.

*Convergence*:

For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1|<\epsilon, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

Since $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1 > 0$ we can rewrite:

$\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1<\epsilon, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

$N>\frac{Log(\alpha)}{Log(\epsilon+1)}, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

Finally $N=\left \lfloor \frac{Log(\alpha)}{Log(\epsilon+1)} \right \rfloor +1$ satisfies $|\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1|<\epsilon$

---

For  $\alpha<1$

*Monotonicity*: By induction:

If n=1 $\rightarrow \alpha<1$

If n=2 $\rightarrow \alpha<\sqrt[2]{\alpha}<1$

If n=3 $\rightarrow \alpha<\sqrt[2]{\alpha}<\sqrt[3]{\alpha}<1$

If n=N $\rightarrow \alpha<\sqrt[2]{\alpha}<\sqrt[3]{\alpha}<...<\sqrt[N]{\alpha}<1$

If n=N+1 $\rightarrow \alpha<\sqrt[2]{\alpha}<\sqrt[3]{\alpha}<...<\sqrt[N]{\alpha}<\sqrt[N+1]{\alpha}<1$

So, for any N, $\sqrt[N]{\alpha}<\sqrt[N+1]{\alpha}$ is always true. Then $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is monotonically increasing.

*Boundedness*:

We have that $\sqrt[N]{\alpha}<1$ is always true. So $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is bounded.

*Convergence*:

For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1|<\epsilon, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

Since $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1 < 0$ we can rewrite:

$\sqrt[n]{\alpha}>1-\epsilon, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

$N<\frac{Log(\alpha)}{Log(1-\epsilon)}, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

Finally $N=\left \lfloor \frac{Log(\alpha)}{Log(1-\epsilon)} \right \rfloor -1$ satisfies $|\sqrt[n]{\alpha}-1|<\epsilon$

Is this correct? I would like to know if there's a way to integrate this "two solutions".

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ is **monotonic**?

Comment: Yep, there's a little typo.

Comment: You can obtain the case $\alpha<1$ from the case $\alpha>1$ simply by taking inverses. But anyway your solution seems correct.

Comment: You've written your convergence proofs backwards.

Comment: For boundedness, you could combine them with the remark that $0 < \sqrt[N]{\alpha} < \max\{\alpha, 1\}$. Ultimately, the suggestion of taking inverses is simpler.